# Why is Magento 2 checkout taking so long to load in local development enviroment?

Tags: magento2, checkout, pagespeed

I am trying to customize the Magento 2 checkout's styling and the page take minutes to load on refresh please help.

I am working on a Mac with Mamp. 
My PHP memory limit is set to `4GB` 
I have turned on all cache but the full page, which is switched off. 
I have disabled:

```
'dev/js/merge_files'
'dev/js/minify_files'
'dev/css/merge_css_files'
'dev/css/minify_files'
```

Please please any suggestions to help the page load in reasonable amount of time whilst developing locally?

Answer (score 0):

**Turn Caching On**

You would be surprised how many times I fixed a client’s slow-M2 problem simply by enabling the cache. “Of course it is slow” – I tell them, “Your cache is off!”.

Go to backend menu System > Cache Management and double check the settings. It should all be green and look like this:

[image]

**Magento 2.2.4 have already fix this issue.**

Check: [Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4868)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I have all the cache switch except full page cache, which I have been advised to switch of when developing. My question or problem is why is specifically the checkout running so slowly? It is not a cache off issue-  do have any other suggestions? please?

Comment: @FrederickDuffield which Magento version you are using?

Comment: @FrederickDuffield magento 2.2.4 already fix this issue. i suggest to upgrade magento version. also I have update my answer.

Comment: @FrederickDuffield, If my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: Thank you @Nikunj getting closer to the crux of the problem! the Git hub issue is very helpful. However, I can't simply upgrade version of Magento because the site is live in production and I don't have permission to upgrade it. Is there away to speed up the load in my local development environment? just whilst I make some minor css-less changes?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 Checkout page is taking time becuase specially its built with knockoutJS.

every component is bind with js because magento2 using knockoutJS so I suggest you to please enable all cache (Full page cache too) even in development mode too and please clean cache when required.

hope this sort brief help you